# Threads, Signals and Child Handling: What a world...What a world

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals

So I have an interesting design problem. I am working on SLES 9+ Linux, kernel 2.6+, and have a multi-threaded application acting as an RPC client. The idea is to have few threads in place to process requests; one such request is to start a "job" as a child process.

Now the problem I'm having is setting up a proper signal handler to deal with a variety of signals. What I've done is set up a another thread for signal handling sitting a `sigwait()` state while blocking all relevant signals in the other threads. The idea is that all signals for the process should be delivered to the signal handling thread and the rest of the threads should worry only about processing requests as they come in.

All of this works great except for those rotten children, always throwing their Frisbees in my backyard and trampling all over my lawn...but in all seriousness, my signal handling thread is not getting the SIGCHLD signal. My best guess as to what is happening here is that because the signal handing thread is not the thread that spawned the child, it will not be the thread that receives SIGCHLD, but instead the my worker threads which did will.

So as for my questions:

1. Am I crazy about SIGCHLD not making it to my signal handler thread?
2. If I am not crazy (it's a stretch, I know), how would you go about fixing this little problem? Currently what I am doing is setting a very simple signal handler for SIGCHLD set up on all threads that simply resends the signal as a SIGUSR2 signal to the process group which is blocked in all threads allowing the signal handling thread. This *seems* to work, however I can't help think either I'm missing something OR there is a better way to *handle* this...he he, get it, *handle* this...okay I'll stop now

`As per David Schwartz request SLES9: NPTL 2.3.5, SLES10: NPTL2.4`

Comment: I am unclear why you want another thread to do the signal handling. It will get called asynchronously anyway by the OS. If there is a bunch of work to be done in the handler, then I would write a simple, quick handler which throws a semaphore and sets off the worker thread.

Comment: You're not crazy. A signal can be handled by *any* thread that doesn't have the signal blocked.

Comment: "What a world" doesn't really describe the problem.

Comment: I agree @nos, the "process signals" are behaving in that manner. The problem is that the SIGCHLD seems to only be delivered to the thread that spawned that child.

Comment: @EdH. I need another thread to do the signal handling since I need to do synchronous work in asynchronous world. By using a thread specifically for signal handling, I am able to synchronize the event and get what I'm calling "proper behavior" without having to worry about corruption (as much). The model I'm using is similar to the on described in this article:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch12lev1sec8.html

Comment: FWIW, it works fine for me on NPTL 2.13 ... so you're definitely not crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit: Because I can't read and you are already doing proper pthread_sigmask calls....)

In the 2.6 kernel, when SIGCHLD is set to ignore/SIG_IGN the kernel will reap child processes for you.  It sounds like if you set up a specific handler for SIGCHLD for your signal handling thread in order to avoid having SIGCHLD set to SIG_IGN/SIG_DFL.

Edit (from comments):
I think you hit an edge case. If you leave it as SIG_IGN in the thread spawning the children, the kernel won't even send SIGCHLD. But if you set it to be handled, then your handler is called instead. I think if you set a handler but then still block the signal in pthread_sigmask, the signal will be delivered to a thread that doesn't have the signal blocked (your `sigwait` thread).

Comment: The default is to set to SIG_IGN, however I did attempt adding SIGCHLD to the sigmask passed in pthread_sigmask and wait on it. The problem I am seeing is that that SIGCHLD signal isn't being sent to the signal handing thread but instead seems to be sent **ONLY** to the thread that spawned the child. The work around I have in place now is to have the parent thread issue a SIGUSR2 to the process group when it gets the SIGCHLD which the signal handler receives and interprets as a child has finished and act accordingly

Comment: I think you hit an edge case.  If you leave it as SIG_IGN in the thread spawning the children, the kernel won't even send SIGCHLD.  But if you set it to be handled, then your handler is called instead.  I wonder if you set a handler but then still block the signal in pthread_sigmask, would that work?

Comment: Oddly enough it does...I guess by forcing a signal handler (in my case I simply use a stub) we "unignore" the signal, however since SIGCHLD still blocked in all threads, due to the signal mask, it winds up getting delivered to the signal handler which is currently in a `sigwait()`, so it gets the signal like I wanted all along.

Do me a favor and add your answer after what you already have in the answer section and I'll go ahead and accept that as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Compile and run this code with roughly the same compiling options as you use to build your program:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buf[512];
    confstr(_CS_GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION, buf, 500);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

[This announcement](http://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/suse_linux_porting_advisories.html) is not quite clear on whether NPTL ships with SLES 9 and, if so, if it's the default. But my bet is that you are using LinuxThreads which does not have the ability to target a signal to a process.

Comment: He did mention Linux 2.6 ... ?